# Amplify alsa capture beyond 100%?

Tags: linux, alsa, capture

I'm using ALSA. The volume of my mic is so low that even 100% of capture volume is not enough in a skype conversation. Is there any way to amplify the capture volume beyond 100%?

I cannot use pulseaudio. Because my computer is very old, using pulseaudio with skype will consume most of the CPU resources so that the quality of video chat become unacceptable.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

use softvol module, It is explained here:

http://blog.tpa.me.uk/2013/10/23/alsa-pre-amp-volume-boost-the-simple-explanation/

```
# Set your DEFAULT device to the softvol plug-in
# NOT to a hardware card device
#
# The "!" means completely override the previous default
# Not just changing/adding to it.
pcm.!default {
  type plug
  slave.pcm "softvol"
}

# Configure softvol
pcm.softvol {
  type softvol

  # Send softvol's output to dmix
  slave {
    pcm "dmix"
    # If you wanted to you could send the output to a card directly
    # But in most cases it's better to send it to dmix and let
    # dmix handle where to send it. You can add a whole extra section
    # to configure dmix and where it sends output, but I'm
    # not covering that here.

    ## Use Card 0 Device 0 instead of dmix
    # pcm "hw:0,0"
    ## Use Card 2 Device 0 instead of dmix
    # pcm "hw:2,0"
  }

  # Add a control slider in your mixer interfaces
  # i.e. KMix and alsamixer
  control {
    name "Pre-Amp"
    card <CardNumberYouWantControlToShowOn>
    # i.e. card 0 or card 2
  }

  # Minimum dB when slider is at 0%
  min_dB -5.0

  # Maximum DB when slider is at 100%
  max_dB 40.0

  # How many levels the slider should go through
  # i.e. how granular do you want your control to be
  resolution 12
}
```